# static method returns empty hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have some code where there are 2 classes, A and and util class with static methods B. The class B has a static method called by A. This static method returns a hashmap (); Although the map is properly built by the static method in clas B,  the map is empty when i call this method of B from A. Any thoughts?

the following is the static method from class B which correctly build the map.

```
package fileutils;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.jar.JarEntry;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;
import com.google.common.io.Files;

public class JarFileUtils {
    //Returns the sql queries as a MAP
public static Map<String, String> getSQLs(String jarFileFullPath){  
    Map<String, String> sqlData = new HashMap<String, String>();
    try {
         JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(jarFileFullPath);
         Enumeration enumeration = jarFile.entries();
         while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()){
             sqlData = getSqlDataHelper(enumeration.nextElement(), jarFile);
         }
         jarFile.close();      
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sqlData;
}

//Helper to fetch SQL info
private static Map<String, String> getSqlDataHelper(Object obj, JarFile jarFile) 
{ Map<String, String> sqls = new HashMap<String, String>();
  JarEntry entry = (JarEntry)obj;

  String path = "/"+entry.getName();
  if(Files.getFileExtension(path).equalsIgnoreCase("sql")){
    InputStream input;
    try {
        input = jarFile.getInputStream(entry);
        sqls.put(Files.getNameWithoutExtension(path), readSqlFile(input));   
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();        
    }
  }
  System.out.println(sqls.toString());
  return sqls;      
}

//Reads the given SQL file
private static String readSqlFile(InputStream input) throws IOException {
      InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(input);
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
      StringBuilder sqlQuery = new StringBuilder();
      String line;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          sqlQuery.append(line);
          sqlQuery.append("\n");
      }
      reader.close();
      return sqlQuery.toString();
    }
}
```

the following is where i call the above static method from class A. the size of this map is zero for some reason.

```
//Get the list of SQLs in the jar file
    Map<String,String> sqlsExtracted = JarFileUtils.getSQLs(currentProjectFullPath);
    System.out.println("size = "+currentProjectFullPath+" = "+sqlsExtracted.size());
```

please advise,

thanks!

Comment: show us some code

Comment: Not to be too harsh to you Rookie, but we need to see some code samples that replicate what you're seeing.  It's tough to just infer what's going on simply by your description.

Comment: code is shared above

Comment: variable 'sqls' is undefined is this code working?

Comment: @Rookie What happened when you ran it through a debugger? Did you perhaps end up in the `catch` block?

Comment: no, i do not end up in a catch block in class B. When i sysout the value of the map (sqlData) just before the map is returned by the static method, i can see the key-values. but when i call the same from class A, the map is empty for some reason

Comment: How are you calling it from A as opposed to B?  Are you supplying the same values?

Comment: @Rookie Can you create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I have provided the code. Basically the class B's getSQls() method takes in the path of a jar file and returns a map of .sql files within it. so if you put the code from Class A in a test class and call class B by giving it the path of any jar which contains sql files, then the problem should recreate

Comment: @Rookie You're putting stuff in `sqlData` but returning `sqls`!

Comment: ...and now the code has changed so much that I doubt we're seeing the real thing. I give up.

Comment: i did that to check if the scope of the variable might be causing issues but it is not. i have corrected the code and still behaves the same

Comment: @Biffen The i have corrected the code to make it more readable for you.

Comment: put some debug statements to verify control flow and see what is happening.

Comment: `getSQLs()` is going through each entry in the jar file, but only returns the result of the last entry. Perhaps the last entry doesn't contain any sql files?

Comment: @Roger.. I see what you are saying. this might be the case, good catch! i am checking on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Adding my comment as a possible answer, since it might point to the problem.*

`getSQLs()` is going through each entry in the jar file, but only returns the result of the last entry. Perhaps the last entry doesn't contain any sql files?